# Elastic search : Searching for integers with wildcards

Tags: search, elasticsearch, wildcard, tire

I am currently using the tire client for elastic search. Lets say I have a field which is indexed as a field of type long in my elastic search mapping.
I am trying to achieve something like this:

```
search.query {|query| query.string "30*", :fields => ['id']}
```

Here 'id' is the long field about which I was talking about. But since I specify the fields in the query, the wildcard doesn't work and I end up getting the exact match as the only result.

But doing the same thing works with the _all search as the field type doesn't matter. I want this wildcard search to work while also searching for the search key in that particular field. Is there any way to do this without changing my mapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @alex on that scripting tip. Finally I found something which worked. Phew!

So I ended up doing this(briefly):

```
search.query do |query|
  query.filtered do |f|
      f.filter :script, { 
    :script => "doc['id'].value.toString() ~= '^30[0-9]*$'"
      }
  end
end
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: How to achieve this by using kibana, is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

I see next solutions:

- use multifield and make this also of a string type (but requires mapping change)
- use range and translate this into something like:

  (from 30 to 39) or (from 300 to 309) or (from 3000 to 3099) 
  or (from 30000 to 30999) or ... (to max value)
- use http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-filter.html and check this using scripting

Comment: Have you come across any tire example for using script? Also, is there anything we can do here by using regex?

Comment: oh, i see you found a solution

Comment: Yes I did. Thanks for the tip. I was never thinking about script.

Comment: Any chance of doing it without using script filter?

Comment: Hey guys, can you tell me in which version they've released `script filter` ?