# How to perform wildcard search on a date field?

Tags: elasticsearch

I've a field containing values like `2011-10-20` with the mapping :

```
"joiningDate": { "type": "date", "format": "dateOptionalTime" }
```

The following query ends up in a ***SearchPhaseExecutionException***.

```
"wildcard" : { "ingestionDate" : "2011*" }
```

Seems like **ES(v1.1)** doesn't provide that much of ecstasy. [**This post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21579342/elastic-search-searching-for-integers-with-wildcards) suggests the idea of scripting (unaccepted answer says even more). I'll try that, just asking if anyone has did it already ?

**Expectation**
A search string `13` should match all documents where the `joiningDate` field has values :

```
2011-10-13
2013-01-11
2100-13-02
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your needs correctly, but I would suggest you to use "**range query**" for the date field.
The code below will return the results what you want to get.

```
{
    "query": {
        "range": {
            "joiningDate": {
                "gt": "2011-01-01", 
                "lt": "2012-01-01" 
            }
        } 
    }
}'
```

I hope this could help you.

#### Edit (Searching date containing "13" itself.)

I suggest you to use "**Multi field**" functionality of Elasticsearch. 
It means you can index "joiningDate" field by two different field type at the same time.
Please see and try the example codes below.

**Create a index**

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/blacksmith'
```

**Define mapping in which the type of "joiningDate" field is "multi_field".**

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/blacksmith/my_type/_mapping' -d '{ 
    "my_type" : {
        "properties" : {
            "joiningDate" : {
                "type": "multi_field",
                "fields" : {
                    "joiningDate" : {
                      "type" : "date",
                      "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
                    },
                    "verbatim" : {
                      "type" : "string",
                      "index" : "not_analyzed"
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
    } 
}'
```

**Indexing 4 documents (3 documents containing "13")**

```
curl -s -XPOST 'localhost:9200/blacksmith/my_type/1' -d '{ "joiningDate": "2011-10-13" }'
curl -s -XPOST 'localhost:9200/blacksmith/my_type/2' -d '{ "joiningDate": "2013-01-11" }'
curl -s -XPOST 'localhost:9200/blacksmith/my_type/3' -d '{ "joiningDate": "2130-12-02" }'
curl -s -XPOST 'localhost:9200/blacksmith/my_type/4' -d '{ "joiningDate": "2014-12-02" }' # no 13
```

**Try wildcard query to the "joiningDate.verbatim" field NOT the "joiningDate" field.**

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/blacksmith/my_type/_search?pretty' -d '{
    "query": {
        "wildcard": {
            "joiningDate.verbatim": {
                "wildcard": "*13*"
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Comment: Ya i'm aware of this, but things get complicated once you try to match by month and day. I'll update the question in a moment to make the specifications clear.

Comment: @blackSmith I've added a new suggestion in the answer.

Comment: I would like to use the DSL script, but see no other options than to use `multi_field` due to version constraint. Now I've to change a lot instead of just tweaking the search query. Thanks anyway.